# Notification in android add two notification

Tags: android, notifications

I am new here,

I have used notification panel in my android application and it is working fine,

My question is about I want to add one more notification from same layout and activity with different information.

Is it possible to do so in android?

Comment: Of course possible I think. Did you try it yet?

Comment: Your question will get more answers if you can show what you've tried and any problems encountered. As it stands it is hard to see how any answer could solve your question because it is not specific.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, simply use a different notification ID when calling `NotificationManager.notify(int id, Notification notification)`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html